# How to hide particular plain text with link from different subscribers

Tags: plugins, urls, text

I have a question about how to hide particular plain text with link from different subscribers?
For example if user_A logins to dashboard page he will be able to see only text with URL "Client A" which will redirect him to his webpage. If user_B logins to Dashboard page he can see Text with URL "Client B"[image]

Do you have any suggestions or plugins how to make it work on custom "Dashboard" Page

Comment: You could create a custom dashboard widget that checks for whatever your condition is - user ID, user role, etc. - and outputs a different link depending on the condition.

Comment: @webElanie, can you please provide some examples how to do it please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.